# Time Format for Filemaker PHP

Tags: php, time, filemaker

I'm having an issue with the FileMaker PHP API. I don't know how to format a time correctly for input into a Time field.

I tried entering a string with the format that the documentation guide says (H:M where H can be 24 hours) and it still doesn't take. I don't know if I'm supposed to change the data type with another function like date() or what.

Edit: A little snippet of code

```
//Date
if($arrDate!=NULL){
    $booking->setField('arrival_date', '07/17/2015');
}
//Time
if($arrTime!=NULL){
    $booking->setField('arrival_time', '11:00:00');
}
$savedBooking = $booking->commit();
```

I replaced the variables for the value fields with what they should be just in case it was something going wrong with them, but it still doesn't work. The date field setting works fine if I comment out the Time section however.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the format that I use:

```
$booking->setField('arrival_date', date ( "n/j/Y H:i:s A" ) );
```

If you're interested in adjusting the time, here's a post to checkout: http://timdietrich.me/blog/php-timezone-arithmetic/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have some validation set up on the "arrival_time" time field. What is the error that is returned by the API? It should return an error code that will tell you more.

Also worth mentioning that FileMaker will inherit the date and time settings from your system settings. For example, date formats are different in Europe than they are in the states. But that time value you give looks like it would work, and you only get an error when setting that field, so I would look to make sure the field is defined correctly.

You can also test by putting that value in via FM Pro and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, after hours struggling with this I realized I had put the wrong field name! Thanks for your help guys. A string of H:M worked perfectly.